# Writing R raster stack to NetCDF

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, netcdf4, ncdf4

I've got an [R grid file](http://www.filedropper.com/tavgm1981_1) containing monthly temperature data for the year 1981 which I read in and tried to write to NetCDF using the following code:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(RNetCDF)

test <- raster('.../TavgM_1981.gri', package = "raster")
rstack = stack(test)

writeRaster(rstack, "rstack.nc", overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF",     varname="Temperature", varunit="degC", 
        longname="Temperature -- raster stack to netCDF", xname="X",   yname="Y",zname="nbands",
        zunit="numeric")
```

This writes the [NetCDF file](http://www.filedropper.com/rstack), but it only seems to have one month (I'm not sure which), instead of the 12 months of the year when I examine it using panoply.

Is it possible to write the NetCDF file and keep as much of the data from the R-grid file as possible? Especially the data for each month!

EDIT:

New working code:

```
test <- brick('/TavgM_1981.gri')
writeRaster(test, "rstack.nc", overwrite=TRUE, format="CDF",     varname="Temperature", varunit="degC", 
        longname="Temperature -- raster stack to netCDF", xname="Longitude",   yname="Latitude", zname="Time (Month)")
```

Comment: The link to the grid file is broken. I'm almost certain your problem is that `test <- raster(...)` only creates a single raster layer. So when you use stack on it you still have a single layer only. The solution is to load the grid file as a `brick` in the first place. But I'd like to check this before posting an answer, if you can fix the link.

Comment: have now fixed the links - sorry, site must not host for long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dww pointed out, to get all layers, this

```
test <- raster('.../TavgM_1981.gri', package = "raster")
```

should be

```
test <- brick('TavgM_1981.grd')
```

The main thing is to replace `raster` with `brick`. Also, the three dots `.../` make no sense. It could be one or two dots (or unnecessary), and the `package = "raster"` argument is meaningless.

Comment: Thank you!  I am now trying to convert the x and y coordinates from 'meters' in the Raster file to lat/lon.